# simple_form gem and specifying possible values of minute input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, simple-form

I use simple_form gem
In my view.html.haml i have code

```
f.input :integration_deadline, :start_year=> Date.today.year, :end_year =>Date.today.year + 2, :order =>[:month, :day, :year, :hour, :minute], :ampm => true
```

Is there any way to specifying possible values for :minute,
for example 00,10,20,30,40,50,60 or 00,30

currently it generates select with options

```
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
...
<option value="60">60</option>
```

instead, i want to get

```
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `:minute_step` option like here:

```
f.datetime_select :integration_deadline, ....., minute_step: 30
```